# Get the count of login datetime and username from the textfile

Tags: c#, .net, string, file, split

I am having a textfile with usename, userid, login and logout time.
From this textfile I need to get the userid and howmany times that user logged in on that particular date. I am doing this one using C# (.NET) in windows applications.
I tried this code but I am getting the whole text into the string strRead. In that strRead I need to get the count of user login basing on date.

```
StreamReader strmrdr = new StreamReader("Logfiles.txt");
            string strRead = strmrdr.ReadToEnd();


Username:Rajini||UserId:abc||Userlogintime:10/19/13 12:33:29 PM||UserLogoutTime:10/19/13 12:33:57 PM

Username:Rajini||UserId:abc||Userlogintime:10/19/13 12:35:29 PM||UserLogoutTime:10/19/13 12:36:57 PM
```

Comment: You will need to do some logic. The code does exactly what it has to do. It reads the txt file into a buffer. There you would do some checks to determine who has logged in/out.

Comment: We definitely need to see an example file to help here. How you are storing the data affects the solution.

Comment: There is no way we could guess what is in that file. You should at least share the structure.

Comment: I updated my question Pls check Thanku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't terribly hard, and since you only need the count based on date and the username, I'd probably eschew lots of the more complicated solutions that attempt to fully parse the format. A simple regex-based solution should suffice here:

```
var loginInfo =
    // Read the lines in the file, one by one
    File.ReadLines(args[0])
        // Get a match with appropriate groups for the individual parts
        .Select(l =>
            Regex.Match(l,
                @"Username:(?<username>[^|]+)\|\|
                  UserId:(?<userid>[^|]+)\|\|
                  Userlogintime:(?<date>\S+)", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace))
        // Create a new object with the user name and date
        .Select(m => new {
            Username = m.Groups["username"].Value,
            Date = DateTime.Parse(m.Groups["date"].Value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"))
        })
        // Group by itself, that is, collapse all identical objects into the same group
        .GroupBy(i => i)
        // Create a new object with user name, date and count
        .Select(g => new {
            Username = g.Key.Username,
            Date = g.Key.Date,
            Count = g.Count()
        });

foreach (var info in loginInfo) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", info.Username, info.Date, info.Count);
}
```

This yields the following output on a slightly expanded dataset for me:

```
Rajini 2013-10-19 00:00:00 2
Test 2013-10-19 00:00:00 1
Rajini 2013-10-20 00:00:00 1
Test 2013-10-20 00:00:00 3
Rajini 2013-10-21 00:00:00 1
```

Comment: That's almost an excellent answer. The only caveat is that you are grouping by time, not just date, unless I'm misreading it.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with the US date format, but I think the date still comes first. `\S+` captures only the date portion, not the time.

Comment: Ah, good point. I missed that. In that case this is my favourite answer at least and is duly up-voted.

Comment: I need to display the actual time when the user logged in instead of showing 00:00:00 can u pls give me an idea

Comment: Which time of the potentially many? You can change the regex to capture the time part as well, and the date format to parse it. Then group by `i => new { Username = i.Username, Date = i.Date.Date }`. That should get you most of the way there.

Comment: How to change the regex to capture the time part I tried in so many ways but still I getting same output.Thanku for your advice

Answer (score 3):

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
string[] words;

System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   words = line.Split("|", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   string userlogintimePart = words[2];
   DateTime loginDate = Convert.ToDate(userlogintimePart.Substring(0, "Userlogintime:".Length));
   if (loginDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
      counter++;
   //This is a simple example, but almost everithing in it what you need
   //continue withadd the username into a key value pair
   //if you find again you increment the value by one
}

file.Close();
Console.WriteLine("{0} member logged in from yestoday", counter);
```

Comment: It was me that down-voted you, as you were offering a guess answer to an unclear question. Since the question has been clarified and your answer improved to reflect what's being asked, I've switched it to an up-vote.

Comment: With this I need to display individual count i.e if user logged in 2 times on 10/22/12 and 5 times on 10/23/12

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx)

While you are reading, you can increment the count of the logins for each day. Though there is nothing wrong with the `ReadToEnd` method.

You would need to parse the string while you are reading. Since it has delimiters, it would be easy to parse. You can use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method for this.

One other suggestion may be to store the login count in another column, for each day while you are writing. This way it would be faster to read.

Answer (score 0):

As various people have suggested, you should read the file line by line.

For each line, you can split it on ||.

I'd recommend then building a dictionary using a combination of username and date as the key. Each time you match a key, increment the value.

That'll give you a login per user per day count as required.